# Exercising Twice a Day

Tags: exercise-frequency

I believe it's ok, but wanted to cross reference. Is it ok to exercise twice a day, 12 hours apart if say, you know next day you will not have chance to exercise?

In this case I'd do low-impact cardio (like jogging instead of jumping jacks and ghost jump ropes), and I'd work a different muscle group.

Any insights, past experiences?

Comment: There are many many athletes that do two or more workout sessions a day for weeks on end. Nobody can tell you if it's right for you or not, the best thing to do is give it a try and see how your body reacts.

Comment: @JohnP Ah, I certainly shall!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by smith288, I too will suggest you to give rest to muscles at least 24hrs(its training experts advice). You need to make sure you don't train for for the same muscles within 24 hrs as your muscles need time to relax.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly fine depending on the exercise.  If you are doing muscle group work, it's typically best to give those a day or so rest but if you're just talking basic low impact cardio stuff; that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely work out twice a day, generally speaking.  If you're talking about light-to-moderate aerobic sessions and split resistance training, you shouldn't have much to worry about.

I'm assuming that you're not focused on any sport-specific performance training, or worried about fine tuning gains for an upcoming bodybuilding competition.  If you're just a dude looking to get/stay fit, your main concern with two-a-days should be avoiding fatigue.

Again, it doesn't sound like you're at risk with the type of programming you noted, but there are multiple ways to monitor your central nervous system (CNS) to make sure aren't taxing it too heavily:

- **Heart Rate monitor:** Take your resting HR every morning.  If it's 6-10 BPM more than average, you might not want to go too intense; any more than that, and you may want to consider an active (or inactive) recovery day.
- **Heart Rate Variability:** One of the most accurate methods to conduct DIY CNS testing, but I haven't found a way to do it accurately without a monitoring device, like OmegaWave or NatureBeat.
- **Grip Testing:** Use a dynamometer to check your grip strength.  If you're ~5 lbs weaker than your average baseline, you may be approaching fatigue, and should ease up that day.
- **CNS Tap Test:** I recently downloaded a version of this old school test on my Android.  I haven't had it long enough to establish a real baseline, but similar to the other methods; if you score significantly lower that day, chill a little bit.
- **General body awareness:** Listen to your body and be honest with what it's telling you.

Comment: Yes, I am exercising to build strength and have life-long fitness